# How to run code based on UIPickerview selections?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I'm making a simple iOS application similar to google docs or other text editor. I created a UIPickerview to change the font size but then I realized that when I chose something, nothing happens. So is there any way I can do this here is my code

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var fontBTN: UIButton!
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayFruits.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return arrayFruits[row]
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    }
    var arrayFruits = [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var aligners: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var foramtters: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var pickerData = ["10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", "24", "26", "28", "30", "36", "48", "72"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self
        arrayFruits = ["10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", "24", "26", "28", "30", "36", "48", "72"]
    }


    @IBAction func aligning(_ sender: Any) {
        switch aligners.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            textView.textAlignment = .left
        case 1:
            textView.textAlignment = .center
        case 2:
            textView.textAlignment = .right
        case 3:
            textView.textAlignment = .justified
        default: break

        }
    }

    @IBAction func formating(_ sender: Any) {
        switch foramtters.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            textView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        case 1:
            textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: textView.text, attributes:
                [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
            textView.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)
        case 2:
            textView.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        default: break

        }

    }

    @IBAction func fontPicker(_ sender: Any) {
        if picker.isHidden == true {
            picker.isHidden = false
            fontBTN.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
        } else if picker.isHidden == false {
            fontBTN.setTitle("Aa", for: .normal)
            picker.isHidden = true

        }
    }


}
```

I have tried doing a `Switch statement`, but I get an error saying `"Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'UIPickerView?'"` I tried googling this up but nothing showed up so I asked this question.

```
switch picker {
        case 0:
            //funtion here
        default:

        }
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Body of `didSelectRow ` is empty so it does nothing when you select item in picker, move your desired code there.

Comment: Do I put a switch statement there?

Comment: And what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: To change the font size of the textview

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    let data: [CGFloat] = [20, 25, 30]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: data[row])
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "\(data[row])"
    }
}
```

So you can run code based on an UIPickerView selection by implementing the `didSelectRow` method as shown above.
**Edit:**
I have changed the code to update the fontSize of a textView.

Answer (score 1):

To change font size of your textView based on picker selection you need to do something like this.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
      if let doubleValue = Double(arrayFruits[row]) {
          let fontSize = CGFloat(doubleValue)
          textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
      }
}
```